# Merge image with jar

Tags: java, image, jar, jframe, jlabel

I made java program to show image. The program needs the image to be in one folder with the jar. Is there way to merge the image with the jar?

```
JLabel image = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("englishv2.PNG"));
```

I will put the `JLabel` in a `JFrame`.

Comment: simply pack the image with the jar.

Comment: How are you generating your jar? Are you using maven or gradle? If so, you probably have all your source code under a folder like "src/main/java". If you create "src/main/resources" and put the image in there, it will be assembled into the jar by maven / gradle and will be on the classpath when your application runs. Now you will be able to access it by using `getResource`, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html#getresource

Comment: @Blip how . . . ?

Comment: @BretC I will try.

Comment: how are you generating the jar file? and where is the location of this image relative to the class file calling it?

Comment: when i made the project with netbeans i made the jar from the program it self with icon and the image in the same folder of the project. @Blip

Answer (score 0):

Now considering that your class from which you have posted the code is `Main.java` in package `myPackage.main` and your image is in folder /myPackage/main folder. Then you have to change the above code to:

```
JLabel image = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(Main.class.getRecource("/myPackage/main/englishv2.PNG")));
```

After this you could export as jar from NetBeans and this would result to the image getting embedded in the jar file.

Comment: http://prnt.sc/cznfdn
This is photo where the folder of the project . where main folder ??

Comment: See also the code http://prnt.sc/cznruf . please give me steps to follow to understand what you mean